# Optimised way to search over 2 milllion poi data in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, spatial

We have over 2 million poi data in our mysql db. At any time we need to find what is the nearest point based on the following formula found at this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abba1/4

```
select *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(
-- latitude
@my_lat) ) * cos( radians( 
destination.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( 
destination.longitude ) - radians(
-- longitude
@my_lon) ) + sin( radians(
-- latitude
@my_lat) ) * sin( radians( 
destination.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
-- table containing targets to compare distance
from destination
order by distance limit 1
;
```

The problem we find this taking too long. Some forum suggest to limit the search based on +1 and -1 the lat and long value. The problem now we need to provide minimal one poi. So any optimisation help on this or better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Geohashing ([Geohasing](http://geohash.org/site/tips.html))

You have to create a geohash for every POI in your table.

And then based on the precision that you choose you can use
`LEFT(your_geohash_column,'c1','c3','c4','c5','c6',c7','c8')`
Where the `c`'s are the 8 neighbors from the center calculated by your desired precision.

Keep in mind that you are limiting the results with the precision which you can consider it a radius.